# Change xampp apache htdocs directory to access localhost from ubuntu and windows

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, localhost, xampp

I'm using ubuntu and windows 7 dualboot,and have xampp installed on both I  want to have access to one localhost directory whether I'm using windows or ubuntu. both systems are installed on the same partition.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question but I haven't seen it properly answered yet. Here is what you need to do:

1. Install XAMPP in Windows and LAMPP in Ubuntu
2. Boot into Ubuntu and record your Windows htdocs folder (say `/media/user/OS/xampp/htdocs`)
3. Go to `/opt/lampp/etc` and edit `httpd.conf` and make the following changes (you will need root permissions to do so)
4. Replace

   ```
   #DocumentRoot "/opt/lamp/htdocs"
   ```

   by

   ```
   #DocumentRoot "/media/user/OS/xampp/htdocs"
   ```
5. Replace

   ```
   Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
   ```

   by

   ```
   Directory "/media/user/OS/xampp/htdocs"
   ```
6. In the

   ```
   IfModule unixd_module
   ```

   section replace

   ```
   User daemon
   Group daemon
   ```

   by

   ```
   User yourUsername
   Group yourGroupname
   ```

   Typically yourUsername and yourGroupname are the same: the name of your Ubuntu user but you can check this out in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/groups`
7. Restart LAMPP services and you should be good to go.

Comment: If you made this change after you already logged in to phpmyadmin, the phpmyadmin session must be deleted, since the permissions for that session are still for the deamon user. Go to `/opt/lamp/temp` and remove the `sess_*` file(s?) there. After reloading phpmyadmin all is well. (and a new session is created for the correct user)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having the "shared" HTDOCS folder on your Windows side as Ubuntu can read NTFS natively.

You will need to use FSTAB to mount your Windows partition when Ubuntu boots so that you can access the web files.

Once you have a regular mount point for the Windows partition you need to create a symbolic link in Ubuntu so that your web files are still accessible by Ubuntu Apache but it can still read from its default location.

E.g. `sudo chown -R $USER /var/www; ln -s /var/www /media/Windows/xampp/htdocs`

I'm only using the above code as an example. Please do further reading to get your scenario correct.